# How to use profiles with Maven and Android properly?

Tags: android, maven

My target is to use two different profiles for different deployment phases (development, release), since release has for example debug flag to false while development has debug flag to true. When I build without profiles, it works without problems. But when I put the build section into a profile, Eclipse complains with the following message: `"Project build error: Unknown packaging: apk"`, although the build itself works.

My questions are:

- How can I get rid of the error message when using profiles (there are
  also solutions at SO which work, but not when using profiles).
- Is it possible to configure a common configuration build base for two profiles while "overriding" some configs in the profile itself? For example profile one has `<debug>true</debug>` and profile two has `<debug>false</debug>` or do I have to write the whole build section in both profiles?

Here is my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.mydomain</groupId>
    <artifactId>myartifact</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>apk</packaging>
    <name>My App</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <platform.version>4.4.2</platform.version>
        <android.version>19</android.version>
        <android.plugin.version>3.8.2</android.plugin.version>
        <java.version>1.6</java.version>
        <android.sdk.path>/opt/android-sdk-linux</android.sdk.path>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <junit.version>4.8.2</junit.version>
        <mockito.version>1.9.5</mockito.version>
        <jackson.version>1.9.13</jackson.version>
        <hamcrest.version>1.3</hamcrest.version>
        <annotations.version>4.1.1.4</annotations.version>
        <supportv4.version>r13</supportv4.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
            <artifactId>android</artifactId>
            <version>${platform.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
            <artifactId>support-v4</artifactId>
            <version>${supportv4.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.nineoldandroids</groupId>
            <artifactId>library</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- LInt Annotations -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
            <artifactId>annotations</artifactId>
            <version>${annotations.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Non Android Tests --><!-- hamcrest must be before JUnit due to build errors -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
            <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
            <version>${hamcrest.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
            <version>${mockito.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
            <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
            <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>devel</id>
                <build>
                <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>

                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.5.1</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <source>${java.version}</source>
                            <target>${java.version}</target>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <artifactId>maven-jarsigner-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>1.2</version>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.5</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
                        <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>${android.plugin.version}</version>
                        <extensions>true</extensions>
                        <configuration>
                            <androidManifestFile>${project.basedir}/AndroidManifest.xml</androidManifestFile>
                            <assetsDirectory>${project.basedir}/assets</assetsDirectory>
                            <resourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/res</resourceDirectory>
                            <nativeLibrariesDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/native</nativeLibrariesDirectory>
                            <sdk>
                                <platform>${android.version}</platform>
                                <path>${android.sdk.path}</path>
                            </sdk>
                            <undeployBeforeDeploy>false</undeployBeforeDeploy>
                            <sign>
                                <debug>true</debug>
                            </sign>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
            </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>development</id>
        <properties>
            <debug>true</debug>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>release</id>
        <properties>
            <debug>false</debug>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>

<build>
    <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>

    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>${java.version}</source>
                <target>${java.version}</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-jarsigner-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <configuration>
                <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
            <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${android.plugin.version}</version>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
            <configuration>
                <androidManifestFile>${project.basedir}/AndroidManifest.xml</androidManifestFile>
                <assetsDirectory>${project.basedir}/assets</assetsDirectory>
                <resourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/res</resourceDirectory>
                <nativeLibrariesDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/native</nativeLibrariesDirectory>
                <sdk>
                    <platform>${android.version}</platform>
                    <path>${android.sdk.path}</path>
                </sdk>
                <undeployBeforeDeploy>false</undeployBeforeDeploy>
                <sign>
                    <debug>${debug}</debug>
                </sign>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

This way you have one common build tag and two profiles, each profile specified whether to debug or not via the properties tag. Then when building you specify your profile like this: `-Pdevelopment` or `-Prelease`. Hope it helps.

Comment: I don't understand how the profile knows that it has to change the configuration of the android-maven-plugin pluging and not one of the others? There are even more modifications than just debug configuration. For example, the release will have "execution" sections with zipalign and so on too. I doubt that I can add `<executions><execution>....</execution></executions>` to one profile and Maven knows that it belongs to the android-maven-plugin?

Comment: I am not sure how to control individual executions within a plugin, but you can definitely control plugins themselves by including this in the configuration tag `<skip>${some.dynamic.property}</skip>` where `some.dynamic.property` is configured by each profile similar to the debug property.